# freeswitch contact header (null) user

Tags: freeswitch, sipjs

i have a freeswitch server and am using external profile to register extension 1000 from SIP.js
the connection goes well and i am able to see auth etc. passing through, however the response of registration has incorrect Contact header. it's missing the user (1000) and i suspect that to be the reason behind why my subsequent steps viz. placing a call to 1000 aren't working

```
sofia status profile external reg

Registrations:
=================================================================================================
Call-ID:        <call-id>
User:           1000@<public-ip>
Contact:        "" <sip:(null)@<public-ip>;fs_nat=yes;fs_path=sip%3A(null)%403.7.130.46%3A57899>
Agent:          JsSIP 3.9.1
Status:         Registered(WS-NAT)(unknown) EXP(2022-09-28 20:04:55) EXPSECS(631)
Ping-Status:    Reachable
Ping-Time:  0.00
Host:           <host>
IP:             <client ip>
Port:           57899
Auth-User:      1000
Auth-Realm:     <public-ip>
MWI-Account:    1000@<public-ip>
```

pls refer the missing user ("") and ("null") in Contact

```
Contact:        "" <sip:(null)@<public-ip>;fs_nat=yes;fs_path=sip%3A(null)%403.7.130.46%3A57899>
```

not an expert at freeswitch. some searching got me this

https://groups.google.com/g/doubango/c/4ys3qizKfPw

```
This issue is caused by an invalid SIP URI used for the public
identity.
This is why the Contact,To and From headers contains a (null) user
name.
Please change the your public identity to a valid SIP/tel Uri. e.g.
sip:ta...@doubango.org
```

but to be honest it isn't so obvious (or should it be?).. looking up to #freeswitch experts here

Comment: can the fellow who downvoted care to comment? noob here trying to get started and its not that i haven't tried solving nor is this the first thing im at. i hope we don't downvote questions without references.

Comment: Try to set caller-ID where you have registered(in phone or dialer)

Comment: that did it. thanks! @HP371 can you please post this comment as an answer so i can accept it as the solution. the issue was on JSSip client side where i was setting contact_uri as registrar server, it should rather be of the form sip://user@ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set caller-ID where you have registered(in phone or dialer)